# Best methods of implementing a sync api

Tags: php, arrays, angularjs

I searched everywhere for this but couldn't get a proper answer.
I'm building a client app (angular) and an api (php). Periodically the server and the client's indexed db needs be in sync.

What i have done so far.

1. once every 10 minutes the clients makes a post ajax call to the server api
2. it send two prams. a. array of data which is a log of changes made to the documents . b. an array of ids which the server should return its documents
3. the server will copy all the data in the array to a collection for later processing. and will return a list of id which successfully copied. the server will also return the documents for the requested array of ids
4. back in the client the angular app will update the documents the server responded and will save the successfully saved ids to the indexed db which will again be send int the next api call.

This is a very simple routine. i just wanna know are there any other methods or standards?

Answer (score 0):

you need to use $timeout or $interval service. if you are using $timeout service in the succuess callback again initiate $timeout service to the api kind of recursive, this will update the same scope model every time and your UI will be updated according to the latest data